# Regular expression in Ruby - extracting from Gutenberg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, seed

I am fairly new to Ruby and I am struggling with a regular expression to seed a database from this text file: http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/673/pg673.txt.

I want the `<h1>` tags as the words for the dictionary database, and the `<def>` tags as the definitions.

I could be quite off base here (I've only ever seeded a db with copy and past ;):

```
require 'open-uri'  

Dictionary.delete_all  

g_text = open('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/673/pg673.txt')   

y = g_text.read(/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/)  
a = g_text.read(/<def>(.*?)<\/def>/)    

Dictionary.create!(:word => y, :definition => a)
```

As you can see, there are often more than one `<def>` for each `<h1>`, which is fine, as I can just add columns to my table for definition1, definition2, etc.

But what would this regular expression look like to be sure that each definition is in the same row as the immediately preceding `<h1>` tag?

Thanks for an help!

Edit:

Okay, so this is what i am trying now:

```
doc.scan(Regexp.union(/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/, /<def>(.*?)<\/def>/)).map do |m, n|
  p [m,n]
end
```

How do I get rid of all of the nil entries?

It seems like regular expression is the only way of making it through the whole document without stopping part way through when an error is encountered...at least after a couple attempts at other parsers.

Comment: Generaly speaking regex are not the correct tool to parse html, there's library to parse DomDocuments. Specially in your case, finding a correct regex will turn in a nighmare.

Comment: Ob Tony the Pony reference.

Comment: Should I be using Nokogiri?

Comment: Thank you for the response Tensibai, but in this text file the def tags are not contained on an h1 branch. Perhaps I am too newbie to post on SO... If so kindly direct me somewhere else

Comment: If its so obligatory then make it

Comment: @Tensibai: the document isn't an html document nor a well formed XML document. Using a DOM parser is totally exclude with a file of this size, because you must load the entire file to use it and build the DOM tree, so it is not the good way. The only possible way with a parser is to use an XML pull parser able to continue when an error is encountered (is Nokogiri::XMLReader able to do that? Must be tested). Tags and syntax are very basic here, so using regex on a file stream in this situation is far to be a bad idea.

Comment: @ all feel free to answer... Was my though while reviewing this question. If it's a list like, a nested loop should do. At home right now, may see tomorrow if no answer untill that

Comment: @casimirandhyppolite I would better aim at a parser like [this for example](https://github.com/KitaitiMakoto/epub-parser/blob/master/README.markdown) as it seems to be an epub format. (it takes advantage of nokogiri, and is the first result on Google for a search on ruby epub parser, at least a starting point as the format is not so basic after a quick look at it)

Comment: @Tensibai the def tags are not nested in the h1 tags, they are in sequence. The "pattern" is h1 followed by 1 or many def, and I need the def tags to "belong" to the first preceding h1 tag. I am not familiar enough with the various parsers to know how to do this. Nokogiri has an index method that might work...i will work on that. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @MarkDRubyist you may achieve that, parsing line by line, making each match to h1 a new key in a hash and subsequents def member of an array in this key... I won't write an answer from phone, I can just give clues for now ;) (but I really don't see a regex only solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I came to (with a local extract for sandbox use):

```
require 'pp' # For SO to pretty print the hash at end

h1regex="h1>(.+)<\/h1" # Define the hl regex (avoid empty tags)
defregex="def>(.+)<\/def" # define the def regex (avoid empty tags)
# Initialize vars
defhash={}
key=nil
last=nil

open("./gut.txt") do |f|
  f.each_line do |l|
    newkey=l[/#{h1regex}/i,1] # get the next key (or nothing)
    if (newkey != last && newkey != nil) then # if we changed key, update the hash (some redundant hl entries with other defs)
        key = last = newkey # update current key
        defhash[key] = [] # init the new entry to empty array
    end
    if l[/#{defregex}/i] then
        defhash[key] << l[/#{defregex}/i,1] # we did match a def, add it to the current key array
    end
  end
end

pp defhash # print the result
```

Which give this output:

```
{"A"=>
  [" The first letter of the English and of many other alphabets. The capital A of the alphabets of Middle and Western Europe, as also the small letter (a), besides the forms in Italic, black letter, etc., are all descended from the old Latin A, which was borrowed from the Greek <spn>Alpha</spn>, of the same form; and this was made from the first letter (<i>Aleph</i>, and itself from the Egyptian origin. The <i>Aleph</i> was a consonant letter, with a guttural breath sound that was not an element of Greek articulation; and the Greeks took it to represent their vowel <i>Alpha</i> with the \\'84 sound, the Ph\\'d2nician alphabet having no vowel symbols.",
   "The name of the sixth tone in the model major scale (that in C), or the first tone of the minor scale, which is named after it the scale in A minor. The second string of the violin is tuned to the A in the treble staff. -- A sharp (A#) is the name of a musical tone intermediate between A and B. -- A flat (A&flat;) is the name of a tone intermediate between A and G.",
   "In each; to or for each; <as>as, \"twenty leagues <ex>a</ex> day\", \"a hundred pounds <ex>a</ex> year\", \"a dollar <ex>a</ex> yard\", etc.</as>",
   "In; on; at; by.",
   "In process of; in the act of; into; to; -- used with verbal substantives in <i>-ing</i> which begin with a consonant. This is a shortened form of the preposition <i>an</i> (which was used before the vowel sound); as in <i>a</i> hunting, <i>a</i> building, <i>a</i> begging. \"Jacob, when he was <i>a</i> dying\" <i>Heb. xi. 21</i>.  \"We'll <i>a</i> birding together.\" \" It was <i>a</i> doing.\" <i>Shak.</i>  \"He burst out <i>a</i> laughing.\" <i>Macaulay</i>.  The hyphen may be used to connect <i>a</i> with the verbal substantive (as, <i>a</i>-hunting, <i>a</i>-building) or the words may be written separately. This form of expression is now for the most part obsolete, the <i>a</i> being omitted and the verbal substantive treated as a participle.",
   "Of.",
   " A barbarous corruption of <i>have</i>, of <i>he</i>, and sometimes of <i>it</i> and of <i>they</i>."],
 "Abalone"=>
  ["A univalve mollusk of the genus <spn>Haliotis</spn>. The shell is lined with mother-of-pearl, and used for ornamental purposes; the sea-ear. Several large species are found on the coast of California, clinging closely to the rocks."],
 "Aband"=>["To abandon.", "To banish; to expel."],
 "Abandon"=>
  ["To cast or drive out; to banish; to expel; to reject.",
   "To give up absolutely; to forsake entirely ; to renounce utterly; to relinquish all connection with or concern on; to desert, as a person to whom one owes allegiance or fidelity; to quit; to surrender.",
   "Reflexively : To give (one's self) up without attempt at self-control ; to yield (one's self) unrestrainedly ; -- often in a bad sense.",
   "To relinquish all claim to; -- used when an insured person gives up to underwriters all claim to the property covered by a policy, which may remain after loss or damage by a peril insured against."]}
```

Hope it can help.

Late edit: there's probably a better way, I'm not a ruby expert. I was just giving a usual advice while reviewing, but as it seems no one has answered this is how I would do it.